# S3 life-cycle is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

S3 life cycle is not working, I have configured this life-cycle policy 2 days back but still, my objects are showing in S3-RRS

[image: Screenshot of s3 life-cycle policy]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check It have enough permission and privilege in your S3 life-cycle process and Check logs

Comment: Yes, S3 bucket doesn't have any customized policy so permission is default & my user has admin permission.

Comment: did this ever got solved? I have the exact same problem, it has been a week since I uploaded the files to S3+lifecycle. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, it was resolved & the issue was in my lifecycle configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process that archives files to **Glacier** can take up to 48 hours to take effect. However, you will receive the billing benefit immediately.

So, check again after 48 hours to confirm whether it is working as expected.

By the way, RRS (Reduced Redundancy Storage) stores data in only two data centers instead of the normal three data centers. Historically it was a lower cost, but these days it is not cheaper, so should be avoided. There is no benefit to using RRS (and it is possibly more expensive).

Comment: I have changed the storage class from RRS to IA, Thanks for this information & still, my all the objects are not in the glacier. It is more than 48 hours also. I am planning to wait 2 more days after that I will raise a ticket to AWS team.